# DataTables - Advanced Search / Column filters?

Tags: javascript, search, filter, datatables

Im new to webdev languages in general so please bare with me.
I'd like to implement search filters (dropdown) to my DataTable

The problem here is, when i select "All" from "Jobs" it won't reset back to defaults,
so how i do this with Javascript?

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/bob69420x/pen/oNeBxxP)

Also is there a better way to do this?
**(Please post your example with the correct code snippet)**

```js
    
    function filterColumn ( i ) {
    $('#ex').DataTable().column( i ).search(
    $('#col'+i+'_filter').val()
    ).draw();
    }
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ex').DataTable();
        
     
    
    $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
    filterColumn( $(this).parents('div').attr('data-column') );
        } );
    } );
    


        $('select.column_filter').on('change', function () {
            filterColumn( $(this).parents('div').attr('data-column') );
        } );
```

```css
body {
    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">        
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<form id="clear">
<div class="row">


<!--------------------------Name-------------------------->
<div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
<div class="form-group" id="filter_col0" data-column="0">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control column_filter" id="col0_filter" placeholder="Name">
</div>
</div>



                  
<!--------------------------Job-------------------------->
<div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
<div class="form-group" id="filter_col1" data-column="1">
<label>Job</label>
<select name="JobID" class="form-control column_filter" id="col1_filter">
<option>All</option>
<option>student</option>
<option>teacher</option>
<option>drive</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>


       

<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="card row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<br>

<header>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="ex" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Job</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>John Doe</th>
<th>student</th>
<th>25</th>
<th>10/31/2018</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>George Clooney</th>
<th>teacher</th>
<th>33</th>
<th>05/22/2018</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>David Trump</th>
<th>drive</th>
<th>25</th>
<th>07/13/2018</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</header>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a small change to your `<option>` elements to fix this.  Make sure they all use `value` attributes - for example:

```html
<select name="JobID" class="form-control column_filter" id="col1_filter">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="student">student</option>
    <option value="teacher">teacher</option>
    <option value="drive">drive</option>
</select>
```

Specifically, make sure the "All" option has an empty string as its option value:

```html
<option value="">All</option>
```

All the other values should match the value you want to filter on.

Without the `value` attributes, DataTables will use the display value for filtering - so, the "All" option will try to find column fields containing the string "all".

```js
$('#col'+i+'_filter').val()
```

When you use the `option` attribute you can override this with an empty string - which means all records will be unfiltered for this column.

That is the only change I made to your codepen. If that is not clear I can provide the full update - but I think that should not be needed here.